# How to combine multiple string list with separator

Tags: c#, arrays, string, list

I have three string list, the purpose is combine these list to a single string with separator.

```
List<string> list1=new List<string>{"A","B","C"};
List<string> list2=new List<string>{"=","<", ">"};
List<string> list3=new List<string>{"1","2","3"};
```

The final output is like following:

```
A=1 AND B<2 AND C>3
```

Is there any easy way to generate the final string? I used for loop, but it seems to be ugly. I know C# string has `Join` method to combine an array with separator. How to combine multiple arrays with separator?

Below is my code:

```
StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
for(int i=0; i< list1.count; i++)
{
    str.AppendFormat("{0}{1}{2} AND ", list1[i], list2[i], list3[i]);
}
str.Length = str.Length -5;
string final = str.ToString();
```

Comment: I realise it doesn't really answer your question, but your problem might be more easily solved if the data was in a multi (2)-dimensional array; or  your three lists were all contained inside a parent list

Comment: Using a for loop for this is absolutely fine. If you really think it looks too ugly you can still wrap it into a seperate method to "hide" the loop in your code.

Comment: You are using lists for everything? Why not a single `List<Comparison>` with properties for `Operator`, `Variable` and `Value`? No need to join multiple collections via index, that's most times a code smell that begs for refactoring. This class could override `ToString` to return what you ask for.

Comment: `str.Length = str.Length -5;` doesn't work `str.Length` is read only

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Use Linq `Zip()` twice:

```
string result = string.Join(" AND ", list1.Zip(list2, (l1, l2) => l1 + l2).Zip(list3, (l2, l3) => l2 + l3));
```

https://dotnetfiddle.net/ZYlejS

Answer (score 10):

You could use a combination of string.Join and linq:

```
string.Join(" AND ", list1.Select((e1, idx) => $"{e1} {list2[idx]} {list3[idx]}"));
```

Comment: Just take care that all listst really have the same size.

Answer (score 3):

You could use one of overloads `EquiZip()` in [MoreLINQ](https://github.com/morelinq/MoreLINQ):

```
var res = string.Join(" AND ", list1.EquiZip(list2, list3, (x, y, z) => x + y + z));
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also use a combination of `string.Join` along with `Enumerable.Range` like so:

```
string result = string.Join(" AND ", Enumerable.Range(0, Math.Min(list1.Count, 
                                    Math.Min(list2.Count, list3.Count)))
                      .Select(i => $"{list1[i]} {list2[i]} {list3[i]}"));
```

if the lists are guaranteed to have the same size then it can be reduced to:

```
string b = string.Join(" AND ", Enumerable.Range(0, list1.Count)
                 .Select(i => $"{list1[i]} {list2[i]} {list3[i]}"));
```